# Assemble strings for particular ID by order of index. Python

Tags: python, string, function, indexing, while-loop

So I have a list of sublists

The first value of the sublist is the ID, the 2nd value is the index.

**Ultimately, i'm trying to assemble strings for each ID in the order of the indices.**

```
raw_IDs = ['TCONS_0040771;1','TCONS_0040771;2','TCONS_0040771;3','TCONS_00040772;1','TCONS_00040772;2','TCONS_00040773;1','TCONS_00040773;2','TCONS_00040773;3','TCONS_00040773;4']

IDs = [['TCONS_0040771',1],['TCONS_0040771',2],['TCONS_0040771',3],['TCONS_00040772',1],['TCONS_00040772',2],['TCONS_00040773',1],['TCONS_00040773',2],['TCONS_00040773',3],['TCONS_00040773',4]]
```

I have a dictionary of sequences for each value so...

```
sequences = []

for k in raw_IDs:
    sequences.append(D_ID_seq[k])
print sequences

sequences = ['AAA','AAB','AAAB','AAAA','BAA','BBA','BBB','CCC','DDD']
```

I am trying to assemble sequences based on IDs, the TCONS_xxx value

```
desired_output = ['AAAAABAAAB','AAAABAA','BBABBBCCCDDD']
```

example: first 3 elements in IDs all have the same ID 'TCONS_0040771'.  However, they have different indices ranging from 1-3.  This repeats for 'TCONS_0040772' for indices 1-2 and 'TCONS_0040773' for indices 1-4.

**the desired output is a combination of all strings gathered from the dictionary values appended to the list called 'sequences' based on the corresponding ID**

Note***
i was thinking of creating a while-loop but they get really confusing and end up running for an infinite amount of time when I try them sometimes.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this data:

```
IDs = [['TCONS_0040771', 1], ['TCONS_0040771', 2], ['TCONS_0040771', 3],
       ['TCONS_00040772', 1], ['TCONS_00040772', 2], ['TCONS_00040773', 1],
       ['TCONS_00040773', 2], ['TCONS_00040773', 3], ['TCONS_00040773', 4]]
sequences = ['AAA','AAB','AAAB','AAAA','BAA','BBA','BBB','CCC','DDD']
```

This code:

```
last_id = IDs[0][0]
res = [sequences[0]]
for index, (id_, _) in enumerate(IDs[1:], 1):
    if id_ == last_id:
        res[-1] += sequences[index]
    else:
        res.append(sequences[index])
    last_id = id_
```

Gives this for `res`:

```
['AAAAABAAAB', 'AAAABAA', 'BBABBBCCCDDD']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# This assumes raw_IDs[] and sequences[] have been defined
IDs = [id.split(';') for id in raw_IDs]

prev_id = None
desired_output = []
for id in IDs.keys()
    if id != prev_id:
        if prev_id:
            desired_output.append(output)
        output = ''
    output += sequences.pop(0)
if output:
    desired_output.append(output)
```